# Swift Performance

Tags: performance, optimization, inline, swift

1. Is the Swift compiler smart enough to optimize away multiple repeated method calls that return the same object? Or, should I first assign the return value to a constant and use that instead?
2. For Example:

   The [Table View Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW15) says that when adding subviews to a `UITableViewCell`'s `contentView`, avoid making them transparent. "Transparent subviews affect scrolling performance because of the increased compositing cost."

   So, I often do the following:

   ```
   class EmployeeCell: UITableViewCell {
       var nameLabel: UILabel
       var titleLabel: UILabel
       // ...

       init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String) {
           nameLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectZero)
           nameLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

           titleLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectZero)
           titleLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

           // ...

           super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
       }
   }
   ```

   Would it be better, however, to first (inside `init`) do `let whiteColor = UIColor.whiteColor()` and then replace each call to `UIColor.whiteColor()` with `whiteColor`?
3. Or, perhaps in this example, I should define a function (inside `init`) that creates a `UILabel` with a `frame` of `CGRectZero` and a `backgroundColor` of `UIColor.whiteColor()` and just call that to initialize each label property. If I do that, [will Swift know to optimize (perhaps inline) that function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24022172/does-swift-use-message-dispatch-for-methods)?

Comment: I don't think it is going to have a meaningful performance impact either way. Regardless of which behavior it has in this specific case,  I don't think it's a good idea to depend on implementation details of the compiler

Comment: @Jiaaro maybe not in such a small example, but if the class did very heavy information, it might be more interesting (for instance if I call this method in a loot over 100 times, and a table view might have 1000 rows). Keep in mind that swift is in a beta. So, the behavior might change.

Answer (score 0):

use swiftc -help There is a lot of options, use -emit-xxxx to see the resulting job in details